# How do I return an enum value with a parameter without using switch?

Tags: ios, swift, enums, switch-statement

I have an `enum` that returns a `string` along with the `parameter` id sent in. But since I only use a single case there's no reason to use a `switch`. So the question is, how do I return the very same thing as below without using `switch`?

```
enum MyEnum  {
    
    case myCase(id: Int)
    
    var description: String {
        switch self {
        case .myCase(let id):
            return "myCase\(id)"
        }
    }   
}
```

I tried doing this:

```
    var description: String {
        return "myCase\(id)"
    }
```

but it doesn't recognize id. In the previous code I used `let id` but that can't be used here. (As a side note, I can't say that I understand how `let id` can be used and return the `parameter` sent in as `let id` creates a new variable, no?)

Comment: You can use [`if case let...`](https://fuckingifcaseletsyntax.com/) if you really hate the word "switch" ;)

Comment: ... or use `guard case .myCase(let id) = self else { return "" }; return `myCase\(id)".  The problem with `if` or `guard` though you have to provide a useless `""` if the test fails, which it won't.  `switch` avoids that by exhaustively covering all (1) cases.  Because of this, I'd stick with `switch`.

Comment: TL;DR you can use `if case let` or `guard case let`, but `switch` is better because it is exhaustive.

Comment: Note that this is pointless if you don't conform the enumeration to `CustomStringConvertible`

Answer (score 1):

Not the best solution, to be honest. You can forget about another cases. Better use `switch case`

```
enum MyEnum  {
    
    case myCase(id: Int)

    var description: String {
        if case let .myCase(id: id) = self {
            return "myCase\(id)"
        }
        
        return "unknown case"
    }
}
```

OR another solution with `guard`

```
enum MyEnum  {
    
    case myCase(id: Int)
    
    var description: String {
        guard case let .myCase(id: id) = self else {
            return "unknown case"
        }
        
        return "myCase\(id)"
    }
}
```

Also you can replace `return "unknown case"` to `fatalError("uknown case")` in case you add a new case and forget it

Comment: I suppose could replace the `return "unknown case"` with a `fatalError()` call.  Still ugly though.  I'd stick with `switch`.

Comment: `fatalError()` isn't good too, but anyways `switch case` would be better

Comment: Even though you only have one case now, the `switch` provides you the advantages of not having to worry about not matching that one case, plus if you or someone else adds a case in the future, the `switch` will notify you by no longer compiling.  That is a nice feature to have.

Comment: @vacawama I agree with you, added that as another option

Comment: I think `fatalError()` may be a little better than returning a default string, but it is a runtime error and not the compile time error that `switch` provides.